# About Uploading photo to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-step-functions

I am developing a software on AWS DynamoDB. I got some UIImages. Where should upload them? S3?

I try to use S3, but it says it needs my photo to be a bundle resource. But what I got is an UIImage.

How can I convert UIImagge to NSBUNDLE?

Comment: Can you please show the exact error in your question?

Comment: There is no error. I haven't written any code yet. I saw the rule of S3. It demands the user to upload a picture in NSBundle. But what I got is an UIImage. How can I convert it to NSBundle

Comment: let ext = "png"
let imageURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("<#image-name#>", withExtension: ext)!

Comment: This is what I got on Google. It needs the picture in NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource

Comment: Have you tried putting the file name where it says:  <#image-name#>?

Comment: No....I thought it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup and execute an upload request:

```
// Configure the authentication
import AWSS3

// configure S3
let S3BucketName = "<#bucket#>"

// configure authentication with Cognito
let CognitoPoolID = "<#cognito-pool-id#>"
let Region = AWSRegionType.<#region#>
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:Region,
    identityPoolId:CognitoPoolID)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:Region, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

// Point to the image you want to upload
let ext = "png"
let imageURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("<#image-name#>", withExtension: ext)!

// Setup the upload request
let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
uploadRequest.body = imageURL
uploadRequest.key = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString + "." + ext
uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
uploadRequest.contentType = "image/" + ext

// Push the image
let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
    if let error = task.error {
        print("Upload failed (\(error))")
    }
    if let exception = task.exception {
        print("Upload failed (\(exception))")
    }
    if task.result != nil {
        let s3URL = NSURL(string: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/\(S3BucketName)/\(uploadRequest.key!)")!
        print("Uploaded to:\n\(s3URL)")
    }
    else {
        print("Unexpected empty result.")
    }
    return nil
}
```

You can now create a UIImage instance by doing:
let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: s3URL)!)